# Nginx caching of uwsgi served static files

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, uwsgi

The django project is deployed using uwsgi as application server, it also serves static files from a specified directory(as shown in the below command) and nginx is used as reverse proxy server. This is deployed using docker.

The uwsgi command to run the server is as follows:

`uwsgi -b 65535 --socket :4000 --workers 100 --cpu-affinity 1 --module wui.wsgi --py-autoreload 1 --static-map /static=/project/static;`

The application is working fine at this point. I would like to cache the static files into nginx server. So i have referred blog https://www.nginx.com/blog/maximizing-python-performance-with-nginx-parti-web-serving-and-caching  and i have included following configuration in my nginx.conf :

```
location ~* .(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg
          |jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid
          |midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
   expires max;
   log_not_found off;
   access_log off;
}
```

After adding this into my Nginx conf, the Nginx server container exits with the following error:

`[emerg] 1#1: invalid number of arguments in "location" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:43`

Is this how uwsgi served static files can be cached into nginx? If yes please suggest me what is gone wrong here.

My complete nginx.conf is as follows:

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
    include     conf/mime.types;

    # the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
    upstream uwsgi {
        server backend:4000; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
    }

    # configuration of the server
    server {
        # the port your site will be served on
        listen      8443 ssl http2 default_server;

        # the domain name it will serve for
        server_name _; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
        charset     utf-8;

        ssl_certificate     /secrets/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /secrets/server.key;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

        # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
        error_page 497 https://$http_host$request_uri;

        # max upload size
        client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste
        uwsgi_read_timeout 600s;

        # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass  uwsgi;
            include     /config/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        }

        location ~* .(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg
                  |jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid
                  |midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        }
    }
}
```

Nginx version: 1.16

Comment: You would usually serve static files from a path in your nginx config, not based on the extension. For a standard Django setup you would take any requests to `/static/` and serve files directly from disk where `collectstatic` has collected them. The docs have more information https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: Yes that could be done but since im using docker containers i.e nginx and python(django) ) the `collectstatic` which executes in python container is served using `uwsgi` ,the nginx will pass the request to `uwsgi`. So static files are present in python container.

Comment: Even if you are in a docker container, it's best to expose these statics through a volume to nginx so that the whole static directory is served directly by nginx

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your config is that the location block has newlines in the list of filenames. I tried `nginx -t -c <filename>` with a modified version of your location block:

```
        location ~* .(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
```

... and this passes the test!

Comment: After updating the nginx.conf with above block, the error does not appear, but the static files does not load in my UI, any suggestions why is this?